# Trying to serialize a c# object into xml. Program crashes without throwing an exception

Tags: c#, xml

Some background info. I have used xsd2code++ to generate c# classes from an xsd file. when I try to serialize an object from that schema the program crashes/quits on that line without throwing an exception. is there something I have missed in the app's config file or is my visual studio just being buggy? The program simply quits when the debugger passes the "string xml = res.Serialize()" line.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Add the payload to the envelope. The payload is a ReservationService.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="env">The envelope</param>
    /// <param name="res">The payload</param>
    /// <returns>The resulting envelope with the payload</returns>
    public static MessageEnvelope AddPayload(MessageEnvelope env, ReservationService res)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            string xml = res.Serialize();
            xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
            env.Payload.Any = xdoc.DocumentElement;
            return env;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(
                        SetLogString(
                            res.ToString(),
                            "Error",
                            "",
                            e.StackTrace));
        }
        return null;
    }

A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Communication Service.exe
The thread 0x3e0c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x4194 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x4cc8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x41bc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[16160] Communication Service.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

edit: added some info that the output console spit out. I wonder why it isn't caught in the try/catch...

edit 2: adding configuration comment at the top of the generated c# file as suggested in comments.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  <auto-generated>
//    Generated by Xsd2Code++. Version 4.0.0.433
//    <NameSpace>Communication.reservation_service</NameSpace><Collection>List</Collection><codeType>CSharp</codeType><EnableDataBinding>False</EnableDataBinding><GenerateCloneMethod>False</GenerateCloneMethod><GenerateDataContracts>False</GenerateDataContracts><DataMemberNameArg>OnlyIfDifferent</DataMemberNameArg><DataMemberOnXmlIgnore>False</DataMemberOnXmlIgnore><CodeBaseTag>Net45</CodeBaseTag><InitializeFields>All</InitializeFields><GenerateUnusedComplexTypes>True</GenerateUnusedComplexTypes><GenerateUnusedSimpleTypes>True</GenerateUnusedSimpleTypes><GenerateXMLAttributes>True</GenerateXMLAttributes><OrderXMLAttrib>False</OrderXMLAttrib><EnableLazyLoading>True</EnableLazyLoading><VirtualProp>False</VirtualProp><PascalCase>False</PascalCase><AutomaticProperties>True</AutomaticProperties><PropNameSpecified>Default</PropNameSpecified><PrivateFieldName>StartWithUnderscore</PrivateFieldName><PrivateFieldNamePrefix></PrivateFieldNamePrefix><EnableRestriction>False</EnableRestriction><RestrictionMaxLenght>False</RestrictionMaxLenght><RestrictionRegEx>False</RestrictionRegEx><RestrictionRange>False</RestrictionRange><ValidateProperty>False</ValidateProperty><ClassNamePrefix></ClassNamePrefix><TrackingChangesEnable>False</TrackingChangesEnable><GenTrackingClasses>False</GenTrackingClasses><HidePrivateFieldInIDE>False</HidePrivateFieldInIDE><EnableSummaryComment>False</EnableSummaryComment><EnableAppInfoSettings>False</EnableAppInfoSettings><EnableExternalSchemasCache>False</EnableExternalSchemasCache><EnableDebug>False</EnableDebug><EnableWarn>False</EnableWarn><ExcludeImportedTypes>True</ExcludeImportedTypes><ExpandNesteadAttributeGroup>True</ExpandNesteadAttributeGroup><CleanupCode>False</CleanupCode><EnableXmlSerialization>True</EnableXmlSerialization><SerializeMethodName>Serialize</SerializeMethodName><DeserializeMethodName>Deserialize</DeserializeMethodName><SaveToFileMethodName>SaveToFile</SaveToFileMethodName><LoadFromFileMethodName>LoadFromFile</LoadFromFileMethodName><EnableEncoding>True</EnableEncoding><EnableXMLIndent>True</EnableXMLIndent><Encoder>UTF8</Encoder><Serializer>XmlSerializer</Serializer><sspNullable>True</sspNullable><sspString>True</sspString><sspCollection>True</sspCollection><sspComplexType>True</sspComplexType><sspSimpleType>True</sspSimpleType><BaseClassName>EntityBase</BaseClassName><UseBaseClass>False</UseBaseClass><GenBaseClass>False</GenBaseClass><CustomUsings></CustomUsings><AttributesToExlude></AttributesToExlude>
//  </auto-generated>
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

edit 3: as suggested in comments I removed the DebuggerStepTrhough attribute to all classes generated by xsd2code++. 
the code exits without going to the finally clause or being caught in a higher catch clause. it crashes the program when the debugger reaches the "Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);" line.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Serializes current ReservationService object into an XML string
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serialize(System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
            System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = encoding;
                xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream, encoding);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

edit 4: problem is solved, there was an unrelated part of the code that made the program crash/quit due to background threads completing execution and ending the program. thank you for the replies.

Comment: Is this happening while you are debugging?

Comment: yes. I'll edit my post with some more info from the output console.

Comment: You should be able to step into the Serialize() method and get more info on where it crashes. It would also be useful to see the configuration for the xsd2code tool. It is persisted in the comment at the top of the generated c#  file.

Comment: I shall try that. I also pasted the configuration as you suggested.

Comment: This instant shut downs without any notification are generally a sign of an error unhandled in a background thread. In the above output, 4 threads are reported to exit with code 259 (0x103) which means STILL_ACTIVE. This is a sign of a background thread exception (possibly null pointer exception on top of that output) is causing your application to crash. What is interesting is, Visual Studio should stop at that exception whatever the conditions are.

Comment: If `res` is null, it throws an exception when serialized and another one whan calling `.ToString()`

Comment: I could not step into the Serialize() method. the program quits as soon as it passes or tries to step into that line. and the running threads are listeners for message queues that this program uses to communicate with. this program is being built as a windows service, but it is not quite ready to be run as one.

Comment: @Thomas res is not null in this case, it is a fully populated object. however for some reason the shouldserialize properties generated by xsd2code++ are set to false in the res object.

Comment: @YvesTkaczyk I did. it was not null.

Comment: Taht Serialize method probably has DebuggerStepThrough Attribute. Can you please remove that and step in again?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post xsd and sample xml file? This might be the easiest way to troubleshoot.

Comment: @YvesTkaczyk I'm sorry, but this is a project I'm working on for a customer, and it would violate my contract to post more revealing things. I have updated the question with more code. I still don't understand why the program simply exits without the exception being caught.